# ios7 xcode 5 localization of storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, localization

I am following this tutorial http://blog.appliedis.com/2013/05/22/localization-of-an-xcode-ios-app-part-2/ to localize my storyboard file but I get stuck at the first step: I have opened the project info tab and checked the "Use Base Internationalization" checkbox, but the appearing window does not show my MainStoryboard.storyboard file.

What is the problem there?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.. Open the MainStoryboard, go to the file inspector in the right pane and click on the "Localize" button.